# ProtoBuf and Julia on Windows: Could not spawn setenv()

Tags: windows, julia, proto

Trying to generate code from a .proto-file from within Julia 1.4.2 on Windows (current version), I encounter an IO error which I struggle to understand.

My working directory contains a "proto"-directory, which itself contains a ProtoBuf-specification file named "Sensor.proto". I have successfully installed ProtoBuf on Julia and, following the [instructions by the package authors](https://github.com/JuliaIO/ProtoBuf.jl/blob/master/PROTOC.md), I wish to generate the proto code in the Julia REPL by typing

```
using ProtoBuf
run(ProtoBuf.protoc(`-I=proto --julia_out=jlout proto/Sensor.proto`))
```

(I have seen the authors' comments with regards to Windows, but my understanding is that, for invoking the above command from within Julia, I should be fine).

The error I encounter is (shortened):

```
ERROR: IOError: could not spawn setenv(`protoc -I=proto --julia_out=jlout proto/Sensor.proto`,[<very long list of paths>]): no such file or directory (ENOENT)
Stacktrace:
 [1] _spawn_primitive(::String, ::Cmd, ::Array{Any,1}) at .\process.jl:99
 [2] #550 at .\process.jl:112 [inlined]
 [3] setup_stdios(::Base.var"#550#551"{Cmd}, ::Array{Any,1}) at .\process.jl:196
 [4] _spawn at .\process.jl:111 [inlined]
 [5] run(::Cmd; wait::Bool) at .\process.jl:439
 [6] run(::Cmd) at .\process.jl:438
 [7] top-level scope at none:0
```

The proto-file is valid; I have been using it in a Python environment successfully. What does the error mean, and how could I fix it?

The `<very long list of paths>` within the above error message is:

```
"PATH=C:\\Users\\fh\\.juliapro\\JuliaPro_v1.4.2-1\\packages\\ProtoBuf\\JY3fQ\\src\\..\\plugin:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\;C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\;C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_191\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\apache-maven-3.6.0\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git LFS;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\170\\Tools\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\DTS\\Binn\\;C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\resources\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\DockerDesktop\\version-bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\miniconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Library\\mingw-w64\\bin;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Library\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Scripts;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\MiKTeX 2.9\\miktex\\bin\\x64\\;C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\CLion 2019.3.2\\bin;;", "USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=UoX", "OPENSSL_CONF=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenSSL-Win32\\bin\\openssl.cfg", "HOMEPATH=\\Users\\fh", "PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC", "NODE_ENV=production", "SESSIONNAME=Console", "SYSTEMROOT=C:\\WINDOWS", "APPDATA=C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Roaming", "PSMODULEPATH=C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules", "COMMONPROGRAMW6432=C:\\Program Files\\Common Files", "PROGRAMDATA=C:\\ProgramData", "PUBLIC=C:\\Users\\Public", "USERDOMAIN=UoX", "JULIA=C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\JuliaPro-1.4.2-1\\Julia-1.4.2\\bin\\julia.exe", "OS=Windows_NT", "PROCESSOR_REVISION=9e0a", "TMP=C:\\Users\\FH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp", "COMSPEC=C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", "JULIA_EDITOR=\"C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\JuliaPro-1.4.2-1\\app-1.47.0\\atom.exe\"  -a", "ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\\ProgramData", "CLION=C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\CLion 2019.3.2\\bin;", "COMPUTERNAME=23-Y1225", "JAVA_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_191", "JULIA_DEPOT_PATH=C:\\Users\\fh\\.juliapro\\JuliaPro_v1.4.2-1;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\JuliaPro-1.4.2-1\\Julia-1.4.2\\local\\share\\julia;C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\JuliaPro-1.4.2-1\\Julia-1.4.2\\share\\julia", "MAVEN_HOME=C:\\Program Files\\apache-maven-3.6.0", "USERNAME=fh", "GIT_LFS_PATH=C:\\Program Files\\Git LFS", "USERPROFILE=C:\\Users\\fh", "PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6", "USERDNSDOMAIN=DS.UoX.COM", "=C:=C:\\Users\\fh\\workspace\\project", "PROGRAMW6432=C:\\Program Files", "TERM=xterm-256color", "TEMP=C:\\Users\\FH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp", "HOMEDRIVE=C:", "WINDIR=C:\\WINDOWS", "NODE_PATH=C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\JuliaPro-1.4.2-1\\app-1.47.0\\resources\\app.asar\\exports", "LOCALAPPDATA=C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local", "PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel", "NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=12", "JULIA_PKG_SERVER=pkg.juliacomputing.com", "ONEDRIVECOMMERCIAL=C:\\Users\\fh\\UoX", "COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files", "UATDATA=C:\\WINDOWS\\CCM\\UATData\\D9F8C395-CAB8-491d-B8AC-179A1FE1BE77", "JULIA_NUM_THREADS=6", "COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\\Program Files\\Common Files", "ONEDRIVE=C:\\Users\\fh\\UoX", "PROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\\Program Files (x86)", "JUNORC_PATH=C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\JuliaPro-1.4.2-1\\.atom", "OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=8", "PROGRAMFILES=C:\\Program Files", "LOGONSERVER=\\\\Y63-XC-021", "DRIVERDATA=C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData", "ATOM_HOME=C:\\Users\\fh\\AppData\\Local\\JuliaPro-1.4.2-1\\.atom", "FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default", "SYSTEMDRIVE=C:", "FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer", "PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64", "OPENBLAS_MAIN_FREE=1"
```

I am completely new to Julia, but I'm familiar with "similar" languages such as Python and, although to a lesser extent, C++ and Java. Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: It means `protoc` can not be found in your setting of `PATH`. Just add it into the `PATH` should be enough.

Comment: @JunTian: Thanks. I have added protoc to ```PATH```. Now I get the more specific error ```'protoc-gen-julia' is not recognized as an internal or external command```. If I understand well, this executable should have been installed together with the Julia-Protobuf Package. Where are Julia packages usually installed, and why doesn't it look in this directory by default?

Comment: Directly from the command prompt, I've been able to generate the Julia-code from the proto specification file via ```protoc -I=proto --plugin=protoc-gen-julia=C:\Users\fh\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.4.2-1\packages\ProtoBuf\JY3fQ\plugin\protoc-gen-julia_win.bat --julia_out=proto_generated proto/Sensor.proto``` Still, it would be more elegant to achieve this directly from within Julia.

Comment: Yeah, agree. Maybe create an issue in ProtoBuf.jl ?

Answer (score 0):

As Jun pointed out in the comments, please open an issue here: https://github.com/JuliaIO/ProtoBuf.jl/issues to document this and hopefully get a more elegant pure Julia solution for it.